# How to get the current time string before 10 a clock in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Using the command:

```
CURRTIME=`date "+%Y%m%d%k%M%S"`
```

I can get the current time string such as "20120827141534". I want to use this string to make a file . But when it is before 10 a clock, it can't runs well. The string will be spearate Because the the hour string has only one digit with space before it. CURRTIME will be like this:20120827 41534. 
How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `%H` instead of `%k`:

```
CURRTIME=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
```

`%k` is space padded (obviously). but `%H` adds a padded 0.